# How do you import products into Magento 2 by using the category ID, instead of the path?

Tags: magento2, import

The default Magento 2 product import feature only allows you to specify the category path string in the import file. How can I import product by using the category ID instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension in the link below allows you to import product into Magento 2, by using the category ID.

https://github.com/EnochDataSystems/ProductImportCategoryId

Comment: the module is not working and have issue in override

Answer (score 0):

i have gone to same module before,but have some problem in di.xml,i have small and effective way to do it,it is simple

Just Override This File :/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/CategoryProcessor.php

### and find function public function upsertCategories()
change whole code of this function like as below

[image]

in this sollution u can set category ids like below
[image]

it will accept category id as well as full category path as default.
Thanks